# Scrollviewer containing Buttons for touchscreen use

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, touchscreen

I am aiming to build a ScrollViewer type of control which holds an array of buttons.
The application using this scrollviewer control will be installed on touchscreen terminals.
The terminals will more than likely be running windows XP.

I want the user to be able to use their finger to scroll through the buttons horizontally when there are more buttons than will fit the viewable area. Note that I dont want to display any scrollbars.

Ive learned that the 'PanningMode' property cannot be used with windows xp but only windows 7 where the touchscreen terminal supports 'Windows Touch'.

Using WPF I have built a screen which includes a scrollViewer control which in turn has a collection of buttons. I did manage to create a panning effect by overriding the windows previewMouseDown, previewMouseMove events but this creates a problem whereby the Operating System does not know if the user has pressed the scrollviewer to select a buton or touched the scrollviewer with the intention of scrolling. Basically the override method will always win and left button pressed will be true.

So i need a way to be able to scroll but still maintain the ability to click(touch) a button within the scrollviewer.

I will attach my sample code below.

If there is a possible way to do this I would be delghted to hear it :) OR!! even if there is such a control out there available to purchase I would also be interested in that.

many thanks!

XAML:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutSelector" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource MainVM}}" Height="100" >
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Width="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" PanningMode="HorizontalOnly" >
                            <!--<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedLayout}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>-->
                            <StackPanel CanHorizontallyScroll="True" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Button x:Name="Test1" Content="Button1" Width="150"/>
                                <Button x:Name="Test2" Content="Button1" Width="150"/>
                                <Button x:Name="Test3" Content="Button1" Width="150"/>
                                <Button x:Name="Test4" Content="Button1" Width="150"/>
                                <Button x:Name="Test5" Content="Button1" Width="150"/>
                                <Button x:Name="Test6" Content="Button1" Width="150"/>
                                <Button x:Name="Test7" Content="Button1" Width="150"/>
                                <Button x:Name="Test8" Content="Button1" Width="150"/>
                                <Button x:Name="Test9" Content="Button1" Width="150"/>
                                <Button x:Name="Test10" Content="Button1" Width="150"/>
                                <Button x:Name="Test11" Content="Button1" Width="150"/>
                                <Button x:Name="Test12" Content="Button1" Width="150"/>
                            </StackPanel>


                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
```

c#:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
using ViewModels;

namespace Views
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Point scrollStartPoint;
    private Point scrollStartOffset;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelCreator.Cleanup();
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ScrollViewer.IsMouseOver)
        {
            // Save starting point, used later when determining 
            //how much to scroll.
            scrollStartPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
            scrollStartOffset.X = ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
            scrollStartOffset.Y = ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;

            // Update the cursor if can scroll or not.
            this.Cursor = (ScrollViewer.ExtentWidth >
               ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth) ||
                (ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight >
                ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight) ?
               Cursors.ScrollAll : Cursors.Arrow;

            this.CaptureMouse();
        }

        base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
            //if (this.IsMouseCaptured)
            //{
                // Get the new scroll position.
                Point point = e.GetPosition(this);

                // Determine the new amount to scroll.
                Point delta = new Point(
                    (point.X > this.scrollStartPoint.X) ?
                        -(point.X - this.scrollStartPoint.X) :
                        (this.scrollStartPoint.X - point.X),

                    (point.Y > this.scrollStartPoint.Y) ?
                        -(point.Y - this.scrollStartPoint.Y) :
                        (this.scrollStartPoint.Y - point.Y));

                // Scroll to the new position.
                ScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(
                    this.scrollStartOffset.X + delta.X);
                ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(
                    this.scrollStartOffset.Y + delta.Y);
            //}

        base.OnPreviewMouseMove(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            this.Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;
            this.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }

        base.OnPreviewMouseUp(e);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after many more hours of fiddling and trial and error it occurred to me that the click event which was what I was wanting to maintain funcionality for was not possible because the mouseCapture event was executed and  holding the mouse preventing from any further action taking place, except for the 'PreviewMouseUp' event which released the mouse when I left clicked.

So what I did was to capture the mouse position on entering or hovering over the scrollviewer and then overriding the 'OnPreviewMouseMove' method for the window to get the new position. The important thing was in the 'MouseEnter' event ( Not overridden ) I am not capturing the mouse therefor the mouse is still allowed to click the buttons contained in the scrollviewer!!

Code shown below!

C#

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
using ViewModels;

namespace Views
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Point scrollStartPoint;
    private Point scrollStartOffset;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelCreator.Cleanup();
    }

    //protected void OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    if (ScrollViewer.IsMouseOver)
    //    {
    //        // Save starting point, used later when determining 
    //        //how much to scroll.
    //        scrollStartPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
    //        scrollStartOffset.X = ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
    //        scrollStartOffset.Y = ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;

    //        // Update the cursor if can scroll or not.
    //        this.Cursor = (ScrollViewer.ExtentWidth >
    //           ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth) ||
    //            (ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight >
    //            ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight) ?
    //           Cursors.ScrollAll : Cursors.Arrow;

    //        this.CaptureMouse();
    //    }

    //    base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
    //}

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ScrollViewer.IsMouseOver)
        {
            // Get the new scroll position.
            Point point = e.GetPosition(this);

            // Determine the new amount to scroll.
            Point delta = new Point(
                (point.X > this.scrollStartPoint.X) ?
                    -(point.X - this.scrollStartPoint.X) :
                    (this.scrollStartPoint.X - point.X),

                (point.Y > this.scrollStartPoint.Y) ?
                    -(point.Y - this.scrollStartPoint.Y) :
                    (this.scrollStartPoint.Y - point.Y));

            // Scroll to the new position.
            ScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(
                this.scrollStartOffset.X + delta.X);
            ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(
                this.scrollStartOffset.Y + delta.Y);
        }

        base.OnPreviewMouseMove(e);
    }

    private void ScrollViewer_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ScrollViewer.IsMouseOver)
        {
            // Save starting point, used later when determining 
            //how much to scroll.
            scrollStartPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
            scrollStartOffset.X = ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
            scrollStartOffset.Y = ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;

            // Update the cursor if can scroll or not.
            this.Cursor = (ScrollViewer.ExtentWidth >
               ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth) ||
                (ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight >
                ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight) ?
               Cursors.Arrow : Cursors.Arrow;
        }
    }
}
}
```

XAML:

```
             <Grid x:Name="LayoutSelector" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource MainVM}}" Height="100" >
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Width="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" PanningMode="HorizontalOnly"
                                      MouseEnter="ScrollViewer_MouseEnter"  >
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedLayout}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>

                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an update after some more fiddling. I like this code better because my previous answer means you hav to drag your finger across the scrollviewer but off the control itself if you want to scroll again... not a big deal but some people might find it a little annoying.

Below is an alternative to show the 'ScrollAll' cursor when the finger touches the control, then by lifting and touching somewhere else you can resume a scroll from a new position without having to drag your finger off the control.

credit to Sacha Barber too whose articles were extremely helpful in helping me to complete this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48871/Friction-Scrolling-Now-An-WPF-Attached-Behaviour-T

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
using ViewModels;

namespace Views
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Point scrollStartPoint;
    private Point scrollStartOffset;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelCreator.Cleanup();
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ScrollViewer.IsMouseOver)
        {
            // Save starting point, used later when determining 
            //how much to scroll.
            scrollStartPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
            scrollStartOffset.X = ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
            scrollStartOffset.Y = ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;

            // Update the cursor if can scroll or not.
            this.Cursor = (ScrollViewer.ExtentWidth >
               ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth) ||
                (ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight >
                ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight) ?
               Cursors.ScrollAll : Cursors.Arrow;

            //this.CaptureMouse();
        }

        base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Cursor == System.Windows.Input.Cursors.ScrollAll)
            if (ScrollViewer.IsMouseOver)
            {
                // Get the new scroll position.
                Point point = e.GetPosition(this);

                // Determine the new amount to scroll.
                Point delta = new Point(
                    (point.X > this.scrollStartPoint.X) ?
                        -(point.X - this.scrollStartPoint.X) :
                        (this.scrollStartPoint.X - point.X),

                    (point.Y > this.scrollStartPoint.Y) ?
                        -(point.Y - this.scrollStartPoint.Y) :
                        (this.scrollStartPoint.Y - point.Y));

                // Scroll to the new position.
                ScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(
                    this.scrollStartOffset.X + delta.X);
                ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(
                    this.scrollStartOffset.Y + delta.Y);
            }

        base.OnPreviewMouseMove(e);
    }

    //private void ScrollViewer_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    if (ScrollViewer.IsMouseOver)
    //    {
    //        // Save starting point, used later when determining 
    //        //how much to scroll.
    //        scrollStartPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
    //        scrollStartOffset.X = ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
    //        scrollStartOffset.Y = ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;

    //        // Update the cursor if can scroll or not.
    //        this.Cursor = (ScrollViewer.ExtentWidth >
    //           ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth) ||
    //            (ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight >
    //            ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight) ?
    //           Cursors.Arrow : Cursors.Arrow;
    //    }
    //}

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;
        this.ReleaseMouseCapture();

        base.OnPreviewMouseUp(e);
    }
}
```

}